# Dealing with "Selected" Option in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
<select id="creditCard" ref="card">
 {this.state.cards.map(function(card){
        return(
          <option value={card.ListId}>{card.FullName}</option>
        )
      }, this)}
    </select>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to grab the selected value from the onClick function but nothing I try seems to work. Any ideas of what i'm missing?

Currently i'm trying `this.refs.card.getDOMNode().value` but it only gives me the text not the selected options value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `refs` ([documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)) and `React.findDOMNode` as shown below to access the `value` as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/s7dntop4/):

```
var Example = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div>
           <select ref="peopleList">
            {this.props.people.map(function(person){
                return(<option value={person.id}>{person.name}</option>)
      }, this)}                      
           </select>           
           <button onClick={ this.handleClick }>Selected?</button>
       </div>
    );
  },
  handleClick: function() {
      alert(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.peopleList).value);      
  }
});

var people = [
{
    name: 'john',
    id: 1    
},
{
    name: 'irma',
    id: 2    
},
{
    name: 'rita',
    id: 3   
}
];

React.render(<Example people={ people }/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Upgraded my React Version, but the value is the text not the id on the value attribute.

Comment: Are you sure your data is correct? My jsFiddle example shows that the `value` does contain the `id` and not the `name`.

Comment: Yep, bad on my part, should have been ListID. This works great!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `onChange` on the `<select>` to grab the current value and do whatever you need to do with it:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
  var selectedValue = e.target.value
  // ...
},

// ...in render()
<select id="creditCard" onChange={this.handleChange}>
```

Comment: I tried a few ways and got somewhere with this option, i'm still having issue as this gives me the text value but not the id i have on the option value attribute.